# After editing a file Mathematica 10 interprets [...]^2 as [...(])^2

Tags: bugs, front-end, mac-os-x, interface, parsing

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 10.2 or later**

---

This is a very weird bug and I don't really know how to reproduce it, so I'll just copy-paste the whole code

```
Manipulate[Row[{DensityPlot[
Cos[k Norm[{x, y} - d {0, 2}] - f Pi t]/Norm[{x, y} - d {0, 2}] + 
 Cos[k Norm[{x, y} - d {0, -2}] - f Pi t]/
  Norm[{x, y} - d {0, -2}], {x, 0, 10}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, ImageSize -> 300, PlotTheme -> "Minimal"],
 Rotate[Plot[(200 + Abs[-2 d + y]^2 + Abs[2 d + y]^2 + 2 Sqrt[(100 + Abs[-2 d + y]^2) (100 + Abs[2 d + y]^2)]Cos[k (Sqrt[100 + Abs[-2 d + y]^2] - Sqrt[100 + Abs[2 d + y]^2])])/(2 f (100 + Abs[-2 d + y]^2) (100 + Abs[2 d + y]^2)), {y, -5, 5}, ImageSize -> 280], -Pi/2]}], {t, 0, 15}, {{f, 5}, 1, 10}, {{k, 5}, 1, 10}, {{d, 1}, 0.5, 3}]
```

Basically this is a simulation of the double-slit interference experiment with a plot of the intensity to the right. Note that **all the squares have to be written by Ctrl-6** so that they are superscript! So, the code looks like this when I open the notebook

[image]

Now try changing the `PlotTheme` by adding a second name, like `"Monochrome"`. Suddenly, all brackets and parentheses go red. Upon evaluation, Mathematica spits out errors as if there are no closing brackets. It seems like everything breaks down the moment I enter the quotation marks `""`.
It is possible that this is a Mac-only bug.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce it. V10 on windows. Screen shot. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NolLy.png)  may be you have some hidden char inserted by mistake. If you post the notebook somewhere may be someone can better help you.

Comment: This happens every time for me, if I (1) paste your code, (2) select it, (3) Cell > Convert To > StandardForm, (4) select the whole string, and (5) type two double quotes.  The first double quote causes the code following it to be interpreted as a string with some `SuperscriptBox`es misplaced, and the second quote causes it to be reinterpreted as code.  Seems like a bug. Try using `^` instead of superscripts.  Report it to Wolfram. (Caveat: I have the last beta V10, Mac OSX 10.9.4.)

Comment: I just want to add that entering quotes before a block of code when I use superscripts very frequently causes the formatting to screw up and for parentheses to no longer be recognized as matching. Often times, deleting the quotes and retyping them causes Mathematica to retry the formatting and that can often times fix the issue. It is very frustrating though and has existed since at least Mathematica 7.

Comment: According to Nasser this is not an issue on Windows, but no on has commented on Linux.  It's still happens for me on Mac OSX and *Mathematica* 10.2.

Comment: Similar or identical question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58416/after-editing-a-file-mathematica-10-interprets-2-as-2), with a very nice animated gif that illustrates the problem.

Comment: [Here](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/) is the link for reporting this bug to Wolfram.

Comment: @JessRiedel The link in your comment that is supposed to link to another question is actually to the one you're commenting to. Perhaps you were referring to [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95351/front-ends-gone-wild-with-named-slots)?

Comment: @MichaelE2 This bug seems to have been resolved in v11.  Can you confirm?

Comment: @QuantumDot Not yet: My institution does not use the Wolfram user portal and has not made V11 available yet :/

Comment: This bug seems to be resolved at least by V11.3.  I have a new copy of V11.3 on Mac OS X, where this doesn't occur anymore. Also see (89648)[https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89648/why-does-the-ver-10-0-frontend-lose-matching-of-parentheses-when-we-insert-quot].