# Bug: quote signs with parentheses followed by superscripts in same cell

Tags: front-end

```
(x + 1)^2
```

where `^2` should be a superscript that I do not know how to display here.

If you type in a pair of quote signs `" "` before or above it in the same cell,

```
""    
(x + 1)^2
```

the back parenthesis becomes smaller and unpaired.

[image]

Version: 10.3, Fedora 21

This shows the behavior in action:

[image]

Comment: I'm not really sure I can reproduce your problem (10.3 on Mac OS X 10.11.1). Which system are you on? And can you post screenshots?

Comment: @Graumagier Added.

Comment: Do not add the [tag:bugs] tag up until your observed behavior has been confirmed by other members.

Comment: @J.M. I see. Thanks.

Comment: Version 10.2 - Linux, can confirm this problem.

Comment: Bug confirmed on 10.0.2.0 for Mac

Comment: Related: [(89648)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89648/why-does-the-ver-10-0-frontend-lose-matching-of-parentheses-when-we-insert-quot) and [(58416)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58416/after-editing-a-file-mathematica-10-interprets-2-as-2) and [(95351)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95351/front-ends-gone-wild-with-named-slots?lq=1). I feel like these should somehow be consolidated. I'm still not sure if anyone has submitted the bug report to Wolfram.